# What to notice when migrating from Magento CE to EE?

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, extensions, migration, ee-1.14.0.1

I developed two modules for Magento CE 1.9.0.1. Now our customer decides to migrate to Magento EE 1.14.0.1. They bought it and I installed the extensions and tested them. They worked with zero problems.

But my development on the extensions is not finished yet and I have to enable some more functionality to them. Now here's the questions:

1. I certainly don't think "seeing" the extension works with no problem is the way to migrate the extension from CE to EE. I think there should be a more reliable way to do this. So from where (or how) could I make sure that my extension works completely well on Magento EE?
2. In more general, what are the differences between Magento CE and EE? Is there anything that extension developers should notice when they're migrating an extension? I could not find anything useful on the web that explains the differences.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start with your second question

> what are the differences between Magento CE and EE?

EE is just CE with some additional modules. [See here a presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jrxq8EH5jUU) that Tim did about the 2 versions.

In your case EE 1.14.0.1 is exactly CE 1.9.0.1 + the modules located in `app/code/core/Enterprise`.

As for the first question....

> So from where (or how) could I make sure that my extension works completely well on Magento EE?

I don't think there is a right answer for that. It depends on what your extension does.
If it's a simple CRUD module (let's say you have a news or a blog module) that is almost independent from the rest of the application it should work on both version without any issues.
But if it affects sections of the application that are changed by the EE additional modules you may or may not get in trouble.
For example if you change something in the way the related products behave you have to make sure it plays well with the rule based product relations from EE.
If you change something in the wishlist you have to make sure it works with multiple wishlists from EE.

[You can find here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/674/146) a list of features that EE offers. Check if one of them might affect your module.

Comment: Only if I watched Tim's presentation couple of days ago .