# Differences between Magento 2 Community and Enterprise extensions in coding wise

Tags: magento2, extensions

I need to install community extension to enterprise, before this I need to know What are the differences between Magento 2 Community and Enterprise in code wise

Answer (score 0):

You should read below links before you buy it.

1) https://bsscommerce.com/blog/magento-2-community-vs-enterprise-edition-comparison/

2) https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-ce-vs-ee.html

3) https://sherocommerce.com/difference-between-magento-2-enterprise-community-edition/

4) https://www.i95dev.com/magento-2-community-edition-vs-enterprise-edition/

5) [Magento2: Community edition Vs Enterprise edition](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90458/magento2-community-edition-vs-enterprise-edition) (please see this as your question is already asked)

6) [When to choose Magento Enterprise edition over Community edition?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/651/when-to-choose-magento-enterprise-edition-over-community-edition?rq=1) (I think this one you should read first, why choose EE over CE)